# jquery element in grails 'params="\'message=\'+message" '

Tags: jquery, grails

i copy this grails code from http://grails.asia/grails-example-application-simple-ajax-chat. it work fine but there is a block of code that i don't know what it's mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Simple Chat</title>
    <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
</head>
<body>
<p id="keypress"> keyCode</p>
<div id="chatMessages"></div>

<input type="text" id="messageBox" name="message" onkeypress="messageKeyPress(this,event);"/>
<div id="temp"></div>
<script>
    function messageKeyPress(field,event) {
        var theCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;

        var text = "";
        //text = "fiel.message =" + field + "<br/>" + "event.keycode= " + event.keyCode +"<br/>" +  "event.which = " + event.which +"<br/>" + "event.charCode = " + event.charCode;
        text = $("#messageBox.message");
        document.getElementById("keypress").innerHTML = text;

        var message = $('#messageBox').val();
        if (theCode == 13){
            <g:remoteFunction action="submitMessage" params="\'message=\'+message" update="temp"/>
            $('#messageBox').val('');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function retrieveLatestMessages() {
        <g:remoteFunction action="retrieveLatestMessages" update="chatMessages"/>
    }
    function pollMessages() {
        retrieveLatestMessages();
        setTimeout('pollMessages()', 5000);
    }
    pollMessages();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what does this code: **params="\'message=\'+message"** mean ?

Comment: That line means it's adding query parameters to the remote call function with the name of `message` having the value from the variable `message`. The variable is assigned a few lines above it and comes from the value of the HTML element with the id of `messageBox` (likely an input or textarea).

Comment: Don't use `remoteFunction()` any more as it is deprecated. Use a normal Javascript (e.g. jQuery) library for doing Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered on the comment ( *@Joshua Moore*) but to just change the status of the question to answered, here you have an  answer.

```
params="\'message=\'+message"
```

Means you are passing a parameter named *message* with value equals to the variable `message` ( defined as `var message`).

this (`\'`) is just skipping the single quote.